# ASP.NET Web Forms: How to reference CheckBoxList items as 'selected' on a table on another page using only C# and ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**Assignment Instructions:**

Develop a simple shopping cart application that uses session objects to store the information. You will have to create an ASP.NET project that contains two web forms. The first web form, ShoppingCart.aspx, allows the user to select items using a set of checkboxes. This page shows also the number of items in the cart.

The second web form, Display.aspx, displays the number of selected items in a table and allows the user to go back to the first web form and continue shopping.

---

- I am using a CheckBoxList to list my products, and I built a table with IDs in the cells to receive the data the user checks off.
- *(I considered the idea of using CheckBox vs. CheckBoxList, but this would not be the appropriate solution and doesn't easily allow counting total items selected)*
- I have tried using cookies and session state variables, but I can't figure out how to associate them to the table.
- I can transfer test data from labels and textboxes, anything with an ID, but not my CheckBoxList items.

**How do I reference which checkboxes are selected on page 1, that will update the desired table cells on page 2, after clicking the 'checkout' button without unique IDs on the list items?**

Example: If... 1lb Dark Roast is selected on page 1 ...
*(identified as 'p001' for product 1 on next page)*

```
<asp:ListItem Value="15.99">1lb Dark Roast</asp:ListItem>
```

On page 2 (Display.aspx) the Amount column should update to '1' beside that product

```
<asp:TableCell ID="p001_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
```

If an item is checked on page 1, this should be the result... (along with the other products).

| Product | Price | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1lb dark Roast | $15.99 | 1 |
| 1lb Med Roast | $15.99 | 0 |

1 = checked, 0 = unchecked (assignment desired outcome shows this table)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

---

Here are snippets from my code, if more is needed I can add a link to the full pages.

Page 1 (ShoppingCart.aspx)

```
ShoppingCart.aspx
------------------
<asp:Label ID="TotalCart_lbl" runat="server" Text="Total Items in your Cart: "></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Shop_ckbx" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="15.99">1lb Dark Roast</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="15.99">1lb Medium Roast</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="12.99">1lb Decaf Roast</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="16.99">1lb Cold Brew</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="10.99">1 box Tea</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="35.99">French Press</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="8.99">CCM Mug</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="UpdateCart_btn" runat="server" Text="Update Your cart" OnClick="UpdateCart_btn_Click"/>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Contents_lbl" runat="server" Text="Update To See Cart Contents"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Cost_lbl" runat="server" Text="Total: "></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Checkout_btn" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Display.aspx" Text="Go to Checkout" />

ShoppingCart.aspx.cs
---------------------
protected void UpdateCart_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         int total = 0; //Total item count

         Contents_lbl.Text = "Your Cart Contains: <br/>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -";
         
         foreach (ListItem listItem in Shop_ckbx.Items)
         {
            if (listItem.Selected == true)
            {
               //Add Text to label
               Contents_lbl.Text += "<br/>&#8226 " + listItem.Text;

               //Count Items in Cart
               total += 1;
            }
         }
         Contents_lbl.Text += "<br/>";

         for (int i = 0; i < Shop_ckbx.Items.Count; i++)
         {
            if (Shop_ckbx.Items[i].Selected)
            {
               cost += Convert.ToDouble(Shop_ckbx.Items[i].Value);
               Cost_lbl.Text = "Total: $ " + cost.ToString();
            }
         }
         //Update total items
         TotalCart_lbl.Text = "Total Items in Your Cart: " + total;
      }

protected void Checkout_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          How do I reference the items in the checklist on page 1 
          to update the table on page 2 without unique IDs on each list item?
      }
```

Page 2 code (Display.aspx)

```
Display.aspx
------------------
<asp:Table ID="Display_tbl" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="Header_row" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" BackColor="#FFCC99">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Product_cell" runat="server" Width="250">Product</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Price_cell" runat="server" Width="100">Price</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Amount_cell" runat="server" Width="100">Amount</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p001">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p001_prod" runat="server">1lb Dark Roast</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p001_price" runat="server">$ 15.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p001_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p002" Width="500px">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p002_prod" runat="server">1lb Med Roast</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p002_price" runat="server">$ 15.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p002_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p003">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p003_prod" runat="server">1lb Decaf</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p003_price" runat="server">$ 12.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p003_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p004">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p004_prod" runat="server">1lb Cold Brew</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p004_price" runat="server">$ 16.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p004_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p005">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p005_prod" runat="server">1 box Tea (50 bags)</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p005_price" runat="server">$ 10.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p005_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p006">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p006_prod" runat="server">French Press</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p006_price" runat="server">$ 35.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p006_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="p007">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p007_prod" runat="server">CCM Coffee Mug</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p007_price" runat="server">$ 8.99</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="p007_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="Total_row">
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Total_prod" runat="server">Total</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Total_price" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell ID="Total_amt" runat="server"></asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
            
<asp:LinkButton ID="Back_linkbtn" runat="server" OnClick="Back_linkbtn_Click">Go Back to the Shop</asp:LinkButton>


Display.aspx.cs
-------------------
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         ShoppingCart prevPage = PreviousPage as ShoppingCart;
         if (prevPage != null) 
         {
              NOT SURE HOW TO LINK TO MY CHECKLIST ITEMS 
              TO UPDATE 'AMOUNT' TABLE CELLS
              
              Also,
              CHECKBOXES ON PREVIOUS PAGE NEED TO STAY SELECTED 
              in order to CONTINUE SHOPPING.
              
         } 
      }

protected void Back_linkbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         Response.Redirect("ShoppingCart.aspx");
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem we have here is of course matching up the “thing” you selected on one page, and then figuring this out on the next web page.

To be fair, the problem here is that no doubt you have to "make up" the data here. And that REALLY hurts this whole process, since you having to type in the data two times (once on this page, and then on the target page). Worse, you have to match up by "text". One little space, period etc. and your whole system will fall down.

I going to suggest we NOT worry and NOT have to match up the values. We can in one shot get rid of a HUGE problem, and ALSO reduce the markup, the code and all your life hassles (well, ok, just the coding part - can't fix everything!!!).

So, I going to suggest that in place of the check box "list", we create a table and use that for BOTH pages. This will then not only keep us out of rooms with padded walls, but we can deal with a "row" of something that you select, and just not give one hoot as to the spelling or even what we place in that row. And by doing this, you could with almost no code changes change the "list" from our table to a database - and the whole she-bang would work!!

So, lets use (create) a table, and not only is this easy, but I think far more clean to setup our data.

So, we will have this at the start of the page (a table and some total values for the WHOLE page class.

```
public class MyFirstOrderPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

private decimal MyTotal = 0;
private int MyTotalQty = 0;
```

Ok, now lets do the sub in this page to load up the above table.

```
public void CreateData()
{
    MyTable.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(int));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));
    MyTable.Columns.Add("Purchased", typeof(bool));

    MyTable.Rows.Add({"11b Dark Roast",15.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"11b Medium Roast",15.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"1b Decaf Roast",12.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"11b Cold Brew",16.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"1 box Tea Brew",10.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"French Press",35.99,1,0,false});
    MyTable.Rows.Add({"CCM Mug",8.99,1,0,false});
}
```

Now not only can you "easy" read the above, but you can change/view and see the columns and then the data follows - so you can see we decided to have a Qty and also a column for the purchased. this will save BUCKETS of code, and BUCKETS of markup. And we can use the above to BOTH pages - no having to have two copies of this list!!!!

Ok, so now we have our table. next up, lets display that table. And we can use VERY much the same grid in our order page as we can in the check out page (saves even more time, more code and even MORE markup!!!).

So, lets use a gridview. We could use a listview and I would consider that if you wanted a cute picture and some more product description. But, gridview is fine.

So, here is the markup for the gridview:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" BackColor="#FFCC99" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" Headerstyle-width="250px" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HeaderText="Price" Headerstyle-width="80px" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Qty" runat="server" Width="60px" 
                        Text ='<%# Eval("Qty") %>' 
                        MyRow = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
                        AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="Qty_TextChanged"
                      />
                    </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Amount" runat="server" width="80px"
                        Text ='<%# FormatCurrency(Eval("Qty") * Eval("Price")) %>' Enabled="false" DataFormatString="{0:C2}"  />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Purchase"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" width="110px" 
                        Checked ='<%# Eval("Purchased") %>' 
                        MyRow = '<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' 
                        AutoPostBack="true" 
                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1"
                        />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="qtycheck" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Checkout_btn" runat="server"  Text="Proceed to Checkout"
            style="width:140px;height:60px;background-color:#FFCC99;border-radius:25px"
            OnClientClick="hasorder();return false;"/>
        <script>
            function hasorder() {
                var CheckQty = document.getElementById("qtycheck")
                if (CheckQty.value > 0) {
                    window.location.href = "/CheckOut.aspx"
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please select at least one Purchase before proceding to check out");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Now that is a bit of markup, but it is STILL much less then say your 2nd page table, and better you see how our 2nd page now is VERY little markup!!

Ok, so we have the above. The only real issue is that when you check a box, we need to total things up. And when you edit or change the qty, then SAME thing - update the totals.

So, the code we have for each part is again rather limited. I'll post in all in one shot:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Web.UI.Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        // ok first page load, now check if reutrn from checkout 
        if (System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"] == null)
        {
            CreateData(); // first time here  - create the data
            System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"] = MyTable;    // save the data table
        }
        else
            // we have data - (so this is user change of mind from checkout page)
            MyTable = System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"];

        // ok, now load our data into the grid
        LoadData(); // load the data
    }
    else

        // this is a post back due to general changes and selections for this
        // page under normal and mutliple operations and choices by the user.

        // we dont' need to re-display the grid - it persists automatic
        // however the datatable variable does NOT persist - so get from session
        MyTable = System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"];
}

public void LoadData()
{
    MyTotal = 0;
    MyTotalQty = 0;
    qtycheck.Value = 0;
    GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox MyAmount = e.Row.FindControl("Amount");
        DataRow MyRow = MyTable.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex);

        MyRow("Amount") = MyRow("Qty") * MyRow("Price");

        if (MyRow("Purchased") == true)
        {
            // total up the qty purcchased and the amount
            MyTotal += MyRow("Amount");
            MyTotalQty += MyRow("Qty");
        }
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        // this is our bottom last footer. 
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = Strings.FormatCurrency(MyTotal);
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = MyTotalQty;
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "Totals:";

        qtycheck.Value = MyTotalQty;     // a hidden control - to check for qty > 0 on checkout
    }
}

protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // user click on purchase a row - udpate totals.
    CheckBox cBox = sender;
    int RowID = cBox.Attributes("MyRow");
    MyTable.Rows(RowID).Item("Purchased") = cBox.Checked;

    // data table has been changed - so we call the load data routine to udpate 
    // our grid
    LoadData();
}

protected void Qty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // user changed the qry in a row
    TextBox tBox = sender;
    int RowID = tBox.Attributes("MyRow");
    MyTable.Rows(RowID).Item("Qty") = tBox.Text;

    // data table has been changed - so we call the load data routine to udpate 
    // our grid
    LoadData();
}
}
```

Now that is a "bit" of code, but again, not really much.

So, you now get this after running:

[image]

So, notice what we do WHEN you check a box!

We simple do this:

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // user click on purchase a row - udpate totals.
    CheckBox cBox = sender;
    int RowID = cBox.Attributes("MyRow");
    MyTable.Rows(RowID).Item("Purchased") = cBox.Checked;

    // data table has been changed - so we call the load data routine to udpate 
    // our grid
    LoadData();
}
```

So, now NO MATCHING problem really exists, does it? You click on a row, and we simply change the Purchased setting (a true/false flag). And that is it - done! no matching required. When you thus check a box, we change the table value, and then simply say to the code will you please re-display the data!!! So NOW we are SAVING all that matching work!!!

Now, the check out code becomes a walk in the park.

when you click on the button to check out, we jump to the checkout page.

The markup is now dead simple - since it much the same as the first page - but no ability to change things. Hence this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
            Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Larger" BackColor="#FFCC99" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
         >

     <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" Headerstyle-width="250px" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HeaderText="Price" Headerstyle-width="80px" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty"  HeaderText="Qty" Headerstyle-width="80px" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount"  HeaderText="Amount" Headerstyle-width="80px" />
     </Columns>
   <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

  </asp:GridView>

        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="ChangeOrder_btn" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/SimpleButton.aspx" Text="Change order"
           style="width:140px;height:60px;background-color:#FFCC99;border-radius:25px"
              />
        <br />
    </div>
```

And the page looks like:

[image]

So, you NOW see why we using a table - since the SAME data now drives both pages, and our problem becomes smaller and smaller - not larger and larger!!

And our code for that checkout page, it is this:

```
class CheckOut : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private decimal MyTotal = 0;
private int MyTotalQty = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable MyTable = System.Web.UI.Page.Session["MyTable"];
    DataView dv = new DataView(MyTable); // we use data view in palce of data table - it can fitler!!

    dv.RowFilter = "Purchased = True";

    GridView2.DataSource = dv;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        MyTotal += e.Row.Cells(3).Text;
        MyTotalQty += e.Row.Cells(2).Text;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = Strings.FormatCurrency(MyTotal);
        e.Row.Cells(2).Text = MyTotalQty;
        e.Row.Cells(1).Text = "Totals:";
    }
}
}
```

So, by build a better design and mouse trap with the first page, and a better approach, then the next page becomes VERY simple, since we re-use the data, re-use the table and in fact darn near re-used the grid too!!!

And to display the order we ONLY have to get the table, and filter the results by purchased.

And the button to go back and change your mind? Well, it just jumps back to the that order page.

So while we did have to build up a bit more "markup" in the first page, we reduced by huge amounts the markup in the 2nd page.

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate this amount of help. This makes soooo much sense. Unfortunately, my 'professor' feels that answering questions is an optional part of the job, so I have had no one to ask and no one I know uses ASP.NET. 

You are a truly awesome person. 

Even though its not the exact same as the example I was given, this is soooo much better and makes 100% more sense. I have been pulling my hair out for a week on this! THANK YOUUUUU

Comment: Excellent! I figured an example with a "table" would be much better. I mean there is a million ways to do these things. The problem with using markup for your first list is that THEN you had a list re-produced on the 2nd page that you have to re-type and everything would have to 100% match - (very difficult). And if you wanted to say play and add a few more rows, then again you would be editing mark-up in two pages - really easy to have that setup fail. And while we had a lot less markup, we did have more code in the first page, but the 2nd page became a walk in the part as  result.